# Isomorphic cokernels giving isomorphic kernels

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

$\require{AMScd}$
This is an issue with a proof related to a characterization of flatness by Eisenbud (in his "Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry", p. 162).

If we have a commutative diagram (of $R$-modules)

\begin{CD}
@. 0 @. 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV\\
@. K @. K'\\
@. @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> A @>f>> A'@>f'>> A'' @>>> 0\\
@. @V\alpha VV @V\alpha' VV @| @.\\
 @. B @>g>> B'@>g'>> A'' @>>> 0\\
@. @V\beta VV @V\beta' VV @. @.\\
@. C @= C\\
@. @VVV @VVV\\
@. 0 @. 0
\end{CD}

with exact columns and rows (note with cokernels in the columns equal and in the rows equal), then $f$ restricts to an injection $K\to K'$. Indeed if $x\in K$ then $\alpha'(f(x))=g(\alpha(x))=0$ so $f(x)\in K'$. Eisenbud then states in his argument that this map is an isomorphism. Does this follow?

The snake lemma doesn't naturally apply since the second row isn't assumed to begin with a monomorphism. From $\alpha'(y)=0$ we can argue that $y=f(x)$ for some $x$ (since $f'(x)=g'(\alpha'(x))=0$), and then we have $g(\alpha(x))=\alpha'(f(x))=0$, but can we then obtain that $\alpha(x)=0$?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a fantastic example of how to ask a question! +1

Comment: Here are the relevant pages: [here](https://ibb.co/P1mdh2k), and [here](https://ibb.co/P6kR0NX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find errata to that book, but it is possible that Eisenbud made a mistake or that the result doesn't follow directly from the diagram.

\begin{CD}
@. 0 @. 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV\\
@. 0 @. R\\
@. @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> R @>=>> R@>0>> 0 @>>> 0\\
@. @V= VV @V0 VV @| @.\\
 @. R @>0>> 0@>0>> 0 @>>> 0\\
@. @V0 VV @V0 VV @. @.\\
@. 0 @= 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV\\
@. 0 @. 0
\end{CD}

Comment: Here are the relevant pages: [here](https://ibb.co/P1mdh2k), and [here](https://ibb.co/P6kR0NX)